# How do you programatically create a TextBox in a WinRT C++ Direct3D app?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, direct3d11

I created a new project in VS2012 on Windows 8: **Visual C++ | Windows Metro Style | Direct3D App**.

This by default creates a working D3D app with a main app class `Direct3DApp1` that derives from `Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::IFrameworkView`.

I need to programatically create a `Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextBox` and somehow insert it into this view. This appears to be easy to do in other project types that define XAML, but this Direct3D App project type does not have XAML.

**How can I overlay a TextBox over the Direct3D graphics that allows the user to pop the keyboard and enter text?**

A fully working VS2012 solution that extends the `Direct3D App` default project would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is demonstrated in the Marble Maze sample (and likely the other DirectX samples since it's in the DirectXApp class)

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/DirectX-Marble-Maze-Game-e4806345

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230257(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This example shows using textbox controls in the Direct2D App (XAML) project template, and not the Direct3D App template, which does not include any XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Of cause, it is to late, but just in case, you need to initialize XAML application first, before using XAML controls:

```
    (void)args; // Unused parameter
::Windows::UI::Xaml::Application::Start(ref new ::Windows::UI::Xaml::ApplicationInitializationCallback(
    [](::Windows::UI::Xaml::ApplicationInitializationCallbackParams^ p) {
        (void)p; // Unused parameter
        auto app = ref new ::MyApp::App();
    }));
```

and set Windows::UI::Xaml::Window::Current->Content

see http://developernote.com/2015/12/initialization-of-uwp-c-xaml-application/ for more information.

I am not sure that Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::IFrameworkView can co-exist with this initialization scenario, so probably you need to refactor your code a bit.

Comment: Please do not only post the link